# ASP and Acess DB - "Like" Query problem

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, ado

```
//ACCESS
SELECT DISTINCT products.imageUrl FROM products WHERE ((products.pcprod_ParentPrd=5573) AND (products.pcprod_Relationship LIKE '*441*'));

//ASP
SELECT DISTINCT products.imageUrl FROM products WHERE ((products.pcprod_ParentPrd="&pidProduct&") AND (products.pcprod_Relationship LIKE '*"&rsCS("idoptoptgrp")&"*'));
```

this query works when i'm manually running the query in Access database. but when I run it from ASP. it doesn't return and rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user670111: In your ASP you have to use `%` instead of `*` as the wild-card character.

So rewrite your query in ASP as

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.imageUrl FROM products WHERE (products.pcprod_ParentPrd = " & pidProduct & ") AND (products.pcprod_Relationship LIKE '%" & rsCS("idoptoptgrp") & "%')
```

Comment: This assumes that in ASP you're using ADO/OLEDB to execute the SQL. If you were using DAO (very unlikely, I know), the * wildcard would work.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: It's about as likely as user670111 responding to say that the problem was solved using my answer. ;-P

Comment: Thanks sir! I'm using ADO/OLEDB

Comment: lol, Why they double minded at first place. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the values of pidProduct & rsCS("idoptoptgrp") are not what you are expecting it to be?

Does it work when you try ...
`((products.pcprod_ParentPrd=" & 5573 & ") AND (products.pcprod_Relationship LIKE '*" & 441 & "*'));`